# Bar chart: how could I align the data with countries when sorting in D3 v5?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am trying to sorting the data for countries in a bar chart now, but when I sort the data in ascending order,the data and countries are not lined up with each other.
Here is the code that I have made (I have to cut off some part of the file, since my code is quite long):

```
"use strict";

var third_width = 1000;
var third_height = 500;
var third_padding = 30;
    
var third_countries = ["Australia", "Austria", "Denmark", "Netherlands","New Zealand", "Norway", "Sweden", "UK","USA","Japan","Poland","Finland","Italy","France","Belgium"]
var third_data = [102, 39, 81, 50, 61, 79, 81, 77, 59, 64, 56, 65, 57, 85, 50];
// The value should be: Australia: 102; Austria: 39; and so on.

// Creating map between two arrays.
const buildMap = (third_countries, third_data) => {
   const map = new Map();
   for(let i = 0; i < third_countries.length; i++){
      map.set(third_countries[i], third_data[i]);
   };
   return map;
};


var numValues = third_data.length;
var sortAscending = function() {
             
   third_svg.selectAll("rect")
            .sort(function(a, b) {
                 return d3.ascending(a, b);
            })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
               return third_xScale(i);
   
            });
}

var sortDescending = function() {
             
   third_svg.selectAll("rect")
            .sort(function(a, b) {
                 return d3.descending(a, b);
            })
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                 return third_xScale(i);
            })
            .transition()
            .delay(function(d,i){
                   return i /numValues * 1000;
            })
           .duration(2000)
           .ease(d3.easeElasticOut);
         
}       



d3.select("#sortascending").on("click", function() { 
   sortAscending();
            
})


d3.select("#sortdescending").on("click", function() { 
   sortDescending();
            
})
```

And here is the result (As you can see, the x-axis is the same before and after my sort).
[image]
[image]
Can you guys help me to know how to align the x-axis data, so countries would be aligned with the right data after sorting?

Thank you!

Comment: You'd have to update the x scale and call the x axis generator on the g that is the parent of the x axis elements.

Comment: Could you explain clearer about what I need to update in the x scale, please?

Comment: If you share the code you use to make the scale and the axis it would be easier to show, explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort countries by value, then sort their names in the same order:

```js
const sortCountries = (countries, values) => {
  let inputCountries = [...countries];
  let inputValues = [...values];
  
  const sortedValues = [...values].sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const sortedCountries = sortedValues.map(val => {
    const index = inputValues.findIndex(v => v === val);
    const country = inputCountries[index];
    inputValues = [...inputValues.slice(0, index), ...inputValues.slice(index + 1)]
    inputCountries = [...inputCountries.slice(0, index), ...inputCountries.slice(index + 1)]
    return country;
  }); 
  return {sortedCountries, sortedValues};
}

const {sortedCountries, sortedValues} = sortCountries(third_countries, third_data);
```

Now, replace `third_data` with `sortedValues` and `third_countries` with `sortedCountries` in your code. See the results in the snippet (based on your prevoious question):

```js
const sortCountries = (countries, values) => {
  let inputCountries = [...countries];
  let inputValues = [...values];
  
  const sortedValues = [...values].sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const sortedCountries = sortedValues.map(val => {
    const index = inputValues.findIndex(v => v === val);
    const country = inputCountries[index];
    inputValues = [...inputValues.slice(0, index), ...inputValues.slice(index + 1)]
    inputCountries = [...inputCountries.slice(0, index), ...inputCountries.slice(index + 1)]
    return country;
  }); 
  return {sortedCountries, sortedValues};
}


const third_width = 1000;
const third_height = 450;
const third_padding = 30;
    
const third_countries = ["Australia", "Austria", "Denmark", "Netherlands","New Zealand", "Norway", "Sweden", "UK","USA","Japan","Poland","Finland","Italy","France","Belgium"]

const third_data = [102, 39, 81, 50, 61, 79, 81, 77, 59, 64, 56, 65, 57, 85, 50];

const {sortedCountries, sortedValues} = sortCountries(third_countries, third_data);



const third_xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(d3.range(sortedValues.length))
  .rangeRound([third_padding ,third_width])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

const third_yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(sortedValues)])
  .range([third_height - third_padding, third_padding]);
                     
const third_xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(third_xScale).tickFormat(function(i) {return sortedCountries[i];})

const third_yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(third_yScale).ticks(5);

const third_svg = d3.select("#chart3")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", third_width)
  .attr("height", third_height);

third_svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(sortedValues)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => third_xScale(i))
  .attr('y', d => third_yScale(d))
  .attr("height", d => third_height - third_padding - third_yScale(d))
  .attr("width", third_xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("fill", d => `rgb(0, 0, ${d * 2})`);

 //Create "Food waste per capita (kg/year)" on Y Axis
 third_svg.append('text')
   .attr('x', 5)
   .attr('y', 20)
   .attr('text-anchor', 'left')
   .style('font-family', 'Helvetica')
   .style('font-size', 'small')
   .text('Food waste per capita (kg/year)');

third_svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "axis")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + third_padding + ",0)")
   .call(third_yAxis);

third_svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+ (third_height - third_padding) + ")")
  .call(third_xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart3" />
```

Comment: I tried to implement it on my code, but for each time I clicked it, there would be another chart appearing in my page. I would add the whole file in my response, so you could see what is my whole idea.

Comment: Please check everything carefully and pay attention to the details. All you need is to add a function, call it for your data, and then replace a few occurrences of the old data with the ordered one. It cannot cause _another chart_ to appear, so the error is probably somewhere else.

Comment: I think your solution does not work here, so we are trying with other approaches for this problem instead.

Comment: I think the solution in the snippet does exactly what is expected by ordering the labels according to the values. I would appreciate if you mark this answer as correct and upvote it and will be glad to answer the other questions as well